# Hot to run a git command in circleCi.yml file, for sending the result to a slack channel

Tags: git, github, slack, circleci

Trying to run a Git command in my circleci's `config.yml` file.
What I want to do, is to run some `git log` command, get the result, and send it to a Slack channel when deployment is successful.

At the moment I am able to send the slack message using the slack orb (with `slack/notify`), but can't find a way to send the `git log` content.

Any ideas?? maybe a short code snippet?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[CircleCI-Public/slack-orb issues 76](https://github.com/CircleCI-Public/slack-orb/issues/76#issuecomment-666449288) suggests (from [this thread](https://discuss.circleci.com/t/git-commit-message-in-environment-variable/533/13)):

```
 echo "export COMMIT_MESSAGE=\"$(git log --format=oneline -n 1 $CIRCLE_SHA1)\"" >> $BASH_ENV
```

In your case, you can use a different variable name (instead of `COMMIT_MESSAGE`).
But the idea remains to define and export an environment variable, that you can use in your slack message.